# AVPlayerLayer as SCNMaterial not rendered, audio playing fine

Tags: avfoundation, calayer, avplayer, scenekit, avplayerlayer

i'm trying to use a AVPlayerLayer as a SCNMaterial to be assigned to a SCNSphere.

Based on: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SceneKit_Slides_WWDC2013/Listings/Scene_Kit_Session_WWDC_2013_Sources_Slides_ASCSlideMaterialLayer_m.html

I create a player, create a player layer and have tried with and without a backgroundLayer to assign as material for my SCNSphere

Issue is, I get the same result reported here:
[SCNMaterialProperty not rendering layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153285/scnmaterialproperty-not-rendering-layer)

Audio plays, video not rendered at all!

The bit of code is quite simple:

```
    // video player
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("tb", ofType: "mp4")
    let url  = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)             // AVPlayer
    player.actionAtItemEnd = .None
    player.play()

    let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)

    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    playerLayer.frame = frame
    playerLayer.player = player


    sceneMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    sceneMaterial.specular.contents = UIColor.whiteColor()
    sceneMaterial.shininess = 0.5
    sceneMaterial.diffuse.contents = playerLayer
    sphere.materials = [sceneMaterial]
```

As mentioned, whether I use a backgroundLayer : CALayer and add the playerLayer as a sublayer gives the same result.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you been able to solve this?

Comment: Also have this problem

Answer (score 1):

@Guig @Byron, take a look at SKVideoNode. I had to use sprikeKit + SceneKit to get what i wanted done

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of SceneKit using a `SKScene` and a `SKVideoNode` is not necessary. You can directly set the `AVPlayer` as the contents of a `SCNMaterialProperty` instance.