# SCNNode geometry material with CALayer

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, scenekit

I have a very basic test scene set up: one camera, default lighting and one slowly rotating cube.

I am attempting to add a video as the texture of the cube and have been following the example [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SceneKitWWDC2014/Listings/Scene_Kit_Session_WWDC_2014_Sources_Slides_AAPLSlideMaterialLayer_m.html) to do so.

Here is the specific block of code that is supposed to add an `AVPlayerLayer` as the material for a node's geometry:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"testVid" withExtension:@"mp4"];
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
if (!asset.playable) {
    NSLog(@"Err 1");
    return;
}
AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
AVPlayerLayer *layer = [[AVPlayerLayer alloc] init];
layer.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
layer.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
[layer.player play];
layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 800);

CALayer *backLayer = [CALayer layer];
backLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
backLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 800);
[backLayer addSublayer:layer];

self.cubeNode.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = backLayer;
//[self.sceneView.layer addSublayer:backLayer];
```

If I add the layer to a UIView (see commented out line) then I get nice playback fine. However, if I add it to the node I just get a black spinning cube (i.e. the `backLayer` shows up but not the video).

Is there something I'm missing? Or is this actually not possible?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153285/scnmaterialproperty-not-rendering-layer